# Fitting an implicit equation into a 3D dataset using sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I have a number of points in 3D space (xi, yi, zi).

I want to fit a certain 3D surface into these points. The surface is only described by an implicit equation:

x²+y²+z² = 1 - a²(x²+y²+z²) + 2*a*z*sqrt(x²+y²+z²)

My goal is to determine the parameter a of this equation.

I've had a look into the functions of scikit-learn, but all seem to require an explicit function z=f(x,y) to determine the parameters. Is this possible at all? If it's not possible with sklearn, other approaches are also welcome.

Comment: This seems an usual nonlinear regression. Please joint to your question an example of data ( representative simplified numerical example, not graph) for concrete explanation of the calculus.

Comment: Hi @JJacquelin, I'll upload sample data later. I have the data points as three numpy arrays `x`, `y` and `z` which contain the coordinates for the data points. Could you tell me which sklearn methods are appropriate for this task? Or even point me to an example where a similar fitting - with an implicit surface equation - is done?

Comment: I see no sample data uploaded later.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, here's sample data as a csv file: https://pastebin.com/7BtaQj6s Heres a visualization of the data https://imgur.com/a/gabqdm2 @JJacquelin

Comment: Thank you but I cannot download it.  A simplified representative data should be sufficient and better to edit calculus and explanation.

Comment: @JJacquelin What is your understanding of simpliified representative data? The csv file I uploaded to pastebin is representative for my problem, it contains sample data points x_i, y_i, z_i. If you would like a simplified version, you may only take very 5th or every 10th data point.

Comment: I cannot upload the data file. So I cannot take only some points. Doesn't matter, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

x^2+y^2+z^2=1-a^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)+2 * a * z * sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)

Let   R = sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)

R^2 = 1-a^2 R^2 +2 * a * z * R

a^2 * R^2 -2 * a * z * R + R^2 = 1

(a * R -z)^2 -z^2 +R^2 = 1

(a(x^2+y^2+z^2)-z)^2 +x^2+y^2 =1

Your data show that x, y, z, are big numbers. It is impossible that the sum of squared big numbers be equat to 1 what ever be the real parameter a.

Thus with your data the problem has no real solution.

Comment: Yup, you're correct. I made an oversight in my question. In addition to the parameters a and b there is an offset of x0, y0, z0 that needs to be determined. The variables x,y,z in the equation are offset by x0,y0,z0 relative to the points xi,yi,zi.

Don't get me wrong, thank you for pointing out this mistake. However, I am more interested in the general approach to solve this problem than the concrete solution for this case. i.e. what algorithms, frameworks, libraries to use

Comment: With offsets they are four parameters : a, x0, y0, z0 to be optimized (I don't see any parameter b in your model equation). This is a non-linear regression problem. The litterature on the subject is extensive. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_regression . In practice one use specialized softwares. Usual method of nonlinear regression are implemented involving iterative calculus starting from "guessed" values of the parameters.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares